# How to punctuate a sentence which ends with a question in a dependent clause?

Tags: punctuation

How to punctuate a sentence which ends with a question in a dependent clause? Should I use "?" or "." at the end?

> 1 One of the biggest questions of my life is that are we just pointless advanced animals emerged by evolution.

> 2 One of the biggest questions of my life is that are we just pointless advanced animals emerged by evolution?

Comment: Neither of your sentences contains a direct question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are repeating the question as a question, you should use quotation marks:

> One of the biggest questions of my life is, "Are we just pointless advanced animals that have emerged through evolution?"

Or you can describe question without phrasing as a question

> One of the biggest questions of my life is whether we are just pointless advanced animals.

You can also quote or describe an open question

> Another question is, "What is the meaning of life?"

> Another question is what the meaning of life is.

Comment: In your first answer I would suggest using a colon following "is" rather than a comma, but other than that it's my preferred response.

Comment: It would be wrong to punctuate like this: Another question is, "What is the meaning of life?".  I mean the "." at the end of the sentence.

Comment: I don't mind it, some consider it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a formal document, such as an essay - there are two possible ways of asking this. The first is to treat the question as though it were direct reported speech, using quotation marks e.g.:

***One of the biggest questions of my life is: "Are we just pointless advanced animals emerged by evolution?".*** (Note that the question mark appears before the close-quotation mark.)

On the other hand you could say it in an indirect-reported way, such as:

***One of the biggest questions of my life is to ask whether we are just pointless advanced animals emerged by evolution.***